# Run python threads on multiple cores

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.4, concurrent.futures

I know that Python 2.7 does not allow one to run multiple threads on different cores, and you need to use the `multiprocessing` module in order to achieve some degree of concurrency. I was looking at the `concurrent.futures` module in Python 3.4. Does using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` allow you to run different threads on different processes, or is it still bound by GIL constraints? If not, is there a way of running threads on different processors using Python 3.4?

For my use case, using multiple processes is absolutely not feasible.

Comment: just curious - under what circumstances would multiple processes be absolutely unfeasible?

Comment: Let's assume you're working on an embedded system with very little memory. It's not a very good idea to spawn multiple processes there, right? Although I agree that Python shouldn't be the language of choice either. It's just a small experiment that I am carrying out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. ThreadPoolExector is just a class to help with scheduling work on multiple threads. All of the normal thread constraints still apply.

To clear up some confusion, threads will run on different processors / cores as the operating system chooses, they just won't run concurrently. The exception is that some C based functions release the GIL temporarily while performing actions not needing the lock.